# Regex: Match patterns except with pattern preceding

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to write a regular expression to match certain patterns except for those with a preceding pattern. In other words given the following sentence:

`Don't want to match paragraph 1.2.3.4 but this instead 5.6.7.8`

I would like to match all `X.X.X.X` that does not have the word `paragraph` in front of it, ie it should only match **5.6.7.8**. My current regex as such seems to match both 1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8. I have switched around the lookaheads but doesn't seem to match my use case.

```
(?<!paragraph)(?:[\(\)0-9a-zA-Z]+\.)+[\(\)0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

I code in javascript.

EDIT: Note that `X.X.X.X` are not fixed at 4 `X`s. They range from `X.X` to `X.X.X.X.X`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern matches because "paragraph" is not the same as "paragraph[space]". Your pattern doesn't have a space. Your text does.

You may want to add the space (perhaps conditionally?) to your lookbehind. Because you want to match a varying number of `X.X.X.X` (you've said `X.X` through `X.X.X.X.X`), we need to include `X.` in the lookbehind as well:

```
const rex = /(?<!paragraph *(?:[\(\)0-9a-zA-Z]+\.)*)(?:[\(\)0-9a-zA-Z]+\.){1,4}[\(\)0-9a-zA-Z]/i;
```

Live Example:

```js
function test(str) {
    const rex = /(?<!paragraph *(?:[\(\)0-9a-zA-Z]+\.)*)(?:[\(\)0-9a-zA-Z]+\.){1,4}[\(\)0-9a-zA-Z]/i;
    const match = rex.exec(str);
    console.log(match ? match[0] : "No match");
}

console.log("Testing four 'digits':");
test("Don't want to match paragraph 1.2.3.4 but this instead 5.6.7.8 blah");

console.log("Testing two 'digits':");
test("Don't want to match paragraph 1.2.3.4 but this instead 5.6 blah");

console.log("Testing two 'digits' again:");
test("Don't want to match paragraph 1.2 but this instead 5.6 blah");

console.log("Testing five 'digits' again:");
test("Don't want to match paragraph 1.2 but this instead 5.6.7.8.9 blah");
```

That expression requires:

- That `paragraph` followed by zero or more spaces possibly followed by `X.` zer or more times is **not** immediately prior to the match; and
- That `X.` is repeated one to four times (`{1,4}`); and
- That `X` immediately follows those three

`X` in my example is `A-Z0-9` and I've made the expression case-insensitive, but you can tweak as needed.

---

Note that lookbehind was only added to JavaScript recently, in ES2018, so support requires up-to-date JavaScript environments. If you need lookbehind on older environments, you might check out Steven Levithan's excellent [XRegex library](http://xregexp.com/).

Also note that variable-length lookbehind like the above is not supported in all languages (but **is** supported in JavaScript...in engines that are up-to-date).

Comment: Hi thanks for your swift answer. Apologies that I may not have been clearer. The `{3}` may not generalise very well because there could be cases where the `X.` may not repeat 3 times. It ranges from `X.X` to `X.X.X.X.X`. If I change `{3}` to `{1,}`, part of the numbering after `paragraph` would still be matched.

Comment: I will update the question to generalise the numbering.

Comment: @Koh - Ah, that will be more complicated and probably involve an alternation...

Comment: @Koh - Updated to handle it. No alternation needed, just adding to the lookbehind. And I went back to your original definition of X.

Comment: Be aware that lookbehind is not supported by all browsers. Moreover variable length lookbehind is not supported in many languages.

Comment: @Toto - But **is** supported in JavaScript.

Comment: Not in Firefox for example, so, don't use it in production.

Comment: @Toto - I mean variable-length is supported in JavaScript. Yes, lookbehind was only added in ES2018 and not all engines have it yet. I assumed since the OP was using it they knew it worked in their target environments (remember that not all JavaScript environments are browsers). I've added both caveats (and a link to XRegex) to the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Great! Your answer helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to match a 4-item group, you can do it like this:

```
(?<!paragraph )([0-9]+.?){4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the Regex iteratively -

1. Ignore any word with preceding with the word 'paragraph' and a white-space.
2. Since your pattern is fixed which will consists of a quadruple of numbers seperated by a period its safe to assume that the minimum number of digits in that quadruple will be 1.
3. Capture the quadruple of numbers in a capturing group to be used later.

Test regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZmDo4E/1/).

```js
const inputData = 'Don\'t want to match paragraph 1.2.3.4 but this instead 5.6.7.8 and 12.2.333.2';
const re = /(?<!paragraph\s+)(\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,})/ig;

const matchedGroups = inputData.matchAll(re);

for (const matchedGroup of matchedGroups) {
 console.log(matchedGroup);
}
```